# Download to folder in server from url, PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have in my database several image links in an array.
I want to download these to a folder in my server renaming the images to 0.jpeg, 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg and so on.
I only managed to insert 1 with the name of 0.jpeg.

```
$result2 = $d->query("SELECT photos AS myfoto From table where id =  15");  

while ($row2 = $result2->fetch()){
    $arrays = $row2["myfoto"];
    foreach(json_decode($arrays) AS $url){
        //prints correctly all files 
        echo $url;
        file_put_contents('/home/my/public_html/place/fotos/[0].jpeg', 
        file_get_contents($url));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error you are getting?

Comment: I only managed to insert 1 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some kind of index that increases, and then can be used in the filename

Easiest way with your current code is to use the index of the array of the results:

```
$result2 = $d->query("SELECT photos AS myfoto From table where id =  15");  

while ($row2 = $result2->fetch()){
    $arrays = $row2["myfoto"];
    foreach(json_decode($arrays) AS $key => $url){
        //prints correctly all files 
        echo $url;
        file_put_contents('/home/my/public_html/place/fotos/'. $key . '.jpeg', file_get_contents($url));
    }
}
```

My preferred code would be:

```
$result2 = $d->query("SELECT photos AS myfoto From table where id =  15");  

while ($row2 = $result2->fetch()){
    $arrays = json_decode($row2["myfoto"]);
    foreach($arrays AS $key => $url){
        //prints correctly all files 
        echo $url;
        file_put_contents('/home/my/public_html/place/fotos/'. $key . '.jpeg', file_get_contents($url));
    }
}
```

not too fond of functions in a foreach-loop definition

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect, sorry my vote for you counts, but is not showed. Thanks again

Comment: added, the first solution works perfect, the second (the preferred) does not, so i stick with the first.